# z-index stacking issue on draggable element (jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue in a jQuery UI app I'm writing (a klondike solitaire game) that happens when I'm attempting to drag a part of a flipped over stack from one stack to another. You can see this illustrated in the screenshot below:

[image: solitaire z-index issue screenshot]

The app in its entirety can be found in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/hy2dvL1u/

I have an idea of what's going wrong but not sure how to engineer it to work as expected.

I initially tried to fix it by adding a class to the hovered over droppable but this only works to the extent that I have to have the draggable at least 50% over the droppable (because I'm using intersect mode on the tolerance option) before the draggable comes to the front. The relevant code:

```
$('.drop-area').droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).closest('.main-stack').addClass('droppable-above');
    },
    out: function (event, ui) {
        $('.main-stack').removeClass('droppable-above');
    },
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('.main-stack').removeClass('droppable-above');
...
```

My guess of what's going on is that the stacks with class .main-stack are absolutely positioned layers with their own z-index values (though not explicitly set in my css) and thus the z-index of the draggable has no bearing on whether it will be above or below a particular .main-stack

Any further clarification on what's going on and what can be done to fix it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution came to me shortly after I posted the question.

I added this to the start: method of the draggable initialization:

```
if ($(this).closest('.main-stack').length) {
    $(this).closest('.main-stack').addClass('dragging-card');
    $(this).closest('.main-stack').siblings().removeClass('dragging-card');
}
```

So my code became:

```
 $('.card').draggable({
    start: function (event, ui) {
        positionTop = $(this).css('top');

        // On drag start check each stack for an empty stack
        $('.main-stack').each(function () {
            if (!$(this).find('.card').length) {
                $(this).droppable('option', 'disabled', false);
                return false;
            }
        });

        // If dragging from a main stack
        if ($(this).closest('.main-stack').length) {
            // Set the class of the draggable's containing stack
            $(this).closest('.main-stack').addClass('dragging-card');
            $(this).closest('.main-stack').siblings().removeClass('dragging-card');
        }

    },
```

And my CSS changed to:

```
.under-card {
    z-index: 1000!important;
}

.ui-front, .top-card {
    z-index: 1001!important;
}

.dragging-card {
    z-index: 1002!important;
}

.ui-draggable-dragging {
    z-index: 1003!important;
}
```